# Parsing full name in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, parsing

I know this is a common question and I've reads all the posts just cannot get it to work so here I am. I have a table called `PUBLICDATA`. In it a table called `PEOPLE` and a column called `NAME`.

In the names column are strings of names formatted like:

```
smith, steve
smith steve a
smith, steve Andrew
smith, steve Andrew robin
```

What I'd like is a quick and dirty script that I can run that will parse the string in the `NAME` column and dump the split names into the `FIRSTNAME`, `MIDDLENAME` AND `LASTNAME` columns that also reside in the `NAMES` table.

ALSO... I have another table (let's say everything is named the same, however the names are like this:

```
steve smith

steve a smith

steve Andrew smith jr

steve Andrew jackson smith
```

Both tables do not have salutation and some have Jr, SR, etc... thank you in advance everyone...

PS.. please no self contained examples as I've seen them around  but cant get them to work with my situation :(

Comment: Quick and dirty in this case just isn't a good idea.  there are tons of examples that illustrate how complex name parsing is.  If you can guarantee that the First name is always the first or last position and the last name is always the first or last than that's one thing, but that's not to say that a Last or first name doesn't contain two names.

Comment: There is no ideal way to handle this.  But you'll want to look into `charindex`  to find the spaces between words, and `substring`, and `length`.  If the answer below is currently over your head, just take it one step at a time.

Comment: Can you update the question with expected output.

Comment: @fireblade I'd like the final output, for the one with lastname, firstname middlename to have the Smith in the lastname field, steve in firstname field and everything in between in middlename field. The name parse with no commas I actually kinda worked out

Comment: I used the below to parse a name like Steve R Smith, but one with a comma separating the last name from first eludes me     SELECT LEFT(Name, CHARINDEX(' ', Name)) AS FirstName,
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', Name) <> LEN(Name) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(Name)) + 1 THEN
SUBSTRING(Name, CHARINDEX(' ', Name)+ 1, LEN(Name) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(Name))-CHARINDEX(' ', Name))
end as middle,
RIGHT( Name, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(Name))) AS LastName
from a01_parse_test

Comment: I have it! But I can only display it using select. What do I need to do to get it to update the table itself? select top 1000 LEFT(Name, CHARINDEX(', ', Name) - 1) LastName, 
        SUBSTRING(Name, CHARINDEX(', ', Name) + 2, CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', Name, CHARINDEX(', ', Name) + 2) = 0 THEN LEN(Name) + 1 ELSE CHARINDEX(' ', Name, CHARINDEX(', ', Name) + 2) END - CHARINDEX(', ', Name) - 2) FirstName,
        RIGHT(Name, LEN(Name) - CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', Name, CHARINDEX(', ', Name) + 2) = 0 THEN LEN(Name) ELSE CHARINDEX(' ', Name, CHARINDEX(', ', Name) + 2) END) Mid
from a01_parse_test

Answer (score 1):

Well you need a split function.  I would split the names using this suggestion:  https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/T-SQL-Script-to-Split-a-308206f3 and put all of the names in their own table.

I would then recommend that if your data really is always structured last name firstname etc that you match on the length of the last name first.  So you take:

```
SELECT name from your_table WHERE Left(name, Length(last_name_from_name_table))=Length(lastname_from_name_table) AND UPPER(Left(name_from_your_table, length(lastname_from_name_table))=UPPER(lastname_from_name_table)
```

and blow that out into a series of cases that capture the names you want with cases for first names, jr, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This works like a charm

```
SELECT LEFT(Name, CHARINDEX(' ', Name)) AS FirstName, CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', Name) <> LEN(Name) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(Name)) + 1 THEN SUBSTRING(Name, CHARINDEX(' ', Name)+ 1, LEN(Name) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(Name))-CHARINDEX(' ', Name)) end as middle, RIGHT( Name, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(Name))) AS LastName from a01_parse_test
```